# Shouldn't this span color be green?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-bugs

Shouldn't the span color should be green, it is red in Chrome.

HTML spec says it should be green, it is green in Firefox.

The HTML spec uses fetch to get the resources referenced by  elements (see [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#obtaining-a-resource-from-a-link-element) and fetch is always an async operation.  So the computed style is gotten before the new stylesheet has loaded, and hence the color should be green.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "data:text/css,div { color: red }";
link.rel = "stylesheet";

var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "data:text/css,div { color: red }";
link.rel = "stylesheet";

document.head.appendChild(link);
document.querySelector("span").style.color = getComputedStyle(div).color;

link.remove();
div.remove();
```

```css
div { color: green }
```

```html
<span>This should be green</span>
```

Comment: Looks green to me? Firefox 57

Comment: It is red on Chrome 63

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen Read question carefully.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen _"it is green in Firefox"_. It's red for me in Chrome

Comment: In Safari it's green

Comment: Why is someone downvoting this and voting for closing, it is genuine question.

Comment: I think it should be red, because at the point your call `getComputedStyle` the dynamic link style has been added.  So here I think Chrome is doing it correctly.

Comment: Why should it be green? You're changing the color of a specific element via its `style` attribute. That's more specific than a rule affecting every div.

Comment: @Andreas https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14489815/

Comment: Due to downvotes I dont ask question on this site anymore. How is this question getting downvote, one try and this is what I get. Closing it. Site is long dead.

Comment: @SurajJain It's a downvote. Don't take it so personally.

Comment: My comment is still valid. The most specific style rule wins. And that's the one where you change the color of the div to red. I don't see why this should be green O.o

Comment: @zfrisch It happens on every post, and really demotivating, why not take personally.

Comment: Interesting, there seem to be different outputs of getComputedStyle… But when tried in the devtools, both return the same color-string.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us why it should be green instead of red ? I agree with @Andreas. Also, please clean up your code to avoid those downvotes.

Comment: _"why not take personally"_ - because it is in no way a personal attack. To be fair to the downvoters, you have given no explanation of why you expect the results that you expect. You have just dumped a block of javascript and expected us to pick through it.

Comment: @SurajJain because this isn't a forum. It's a question and answer site. It seems crude at first because when you're new it's hard to grasp the formatting and the reasons why you may be downvoted, but honestly it helps make it easier to reference questions and answers in the future. To answer your question, you shouldn't take it personally because it's not personal, it's quality upkeep, and it can obviously have human error applied to it. Someone probably saw that, in their browser, your question was unnecessary since they were in firefox. It isn't the end of the world. It's not an attack.

Comment: CSS specificity: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: `green per HTML spec.`  I wonder what part of the spec this refers too?, as logically running the code through my head, it should be `red`..

Comment: @Keith Updated.

Comment: @Andreas Updated

Comment: "_So the computed style is gotten before the new stylesheet has loaded_" You have no proof of that

Comment: @SergeK. Async handler is only executed after stack is empty.

Comment: `The HTML spec uses fetch`  But this is using a data uri, I've just checked the spec on this and I see no mention of it having to be `async`, and for me makes no sense for it to be either.

Comment: @Keith In general, data: URI decoding and CSS parsing can be expensive operations, and requiring them to be sync doesn't make sense.  So I'm not sure why Blink is doing the whole thing synchronously.

Comment: @SurajJain Even if the fetch operation would be async and finished after JS execution, your CSS is _inline_, so there is no fetch operation of it, it *is* loaded before JS execution.

Comment: @SergeK. That is why span should be green

Comment: @SergeK. getComputedStyle(div).color gives green as div color was green.

Comment: @SurajJain Actually, yes.  Thinking about this, I agree.  If a Url is a link or a data uri, it should behave consistently..  Green it should be, obviously Chrome is not waiting.

Comment: @Keith You can remove your downvote.

Comment: @SurajJain I can't remove a downvote I didn't make.. :)

Comment: No it shouldn't be green. 1. Your CSS is parsed. (div is green) 2. You add a CSS using JS (div is red) 3. You call `getComputedStyle` -> *div is red*

Comment: @Keith Oh, I thought you did downvoted, people here usually do downvotes like that only, no much penalty, there is 5 downvotes. So i thought you did. Thanks

Comment: @SergeK.  I think the point is, even though this is a data uri, it should be loaded `async`, if you follow the code using this rule, it would indeed be green.  Interesting topic, in fact I'm going to up-vote.. :)

Comment: @Keith Oh, I get it. But it doesn't change my point, you can't be sure (even if it's async) that the async call will or will not finish after `getComputedStyle`. Maybe `getComputedStyle` forces the browser to finish this kind of requests _before_ it returns.

Comment: @SergeK. You know call maybe get finished earlier, but javascript won't look at it till its stack is empty,. Is there any confusion?

Comment: @Turnip Sorry, updated.

Comment: @SergeK. Is your doubt cleared?

Comment: @Andreas Please see the question again.

Comment: @SurajJain Nope. I don't get why you're certain that `getComputedStyle` will be called before the link is added and parsed.

Comment: Because say async function is completed first, then also the handler that awaits it completion, won't execute until the stack is cleared. that is how event loop works. Does this make sense

Answer (score 2):

To make this easier to analyze, I've reduced your sample to remove the duplicate and irrelevant lines; the following is enough to reproduce the issue:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "data:text/css,div { color: red }";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.head.appendChild(link);

document.querySelector("span").style.color = getComputedStyle(div).color;
```

```css
div {color:green}
```

```html
<span>This is a span</span>
<div>this is a div</div>
```

So what's going on here is, there's inline CSS that says divs should be green; you generate a text/css link that sets divs to red, and append that to the document head.   Then you use `getComputedStyle` to copy the color from the div onto the span.

In Safari, Chrome, and Edge, both lines end up red; in Firefox the span is green and the div is red.

BUT!  on first load, or if you load this page in Safari <strike>or Chrome</strike> with a clean, empty cache<sup>*</sup> you'll see the same behavior as in Firefox: green span and red div.  Edge never behaves like FF, it's always red for both even on first load.

<sup>*</sup>  (In Safari you can just use a private browsing window. I could swear I was seeing the same in Chrome at one point but am no longer able to reproduce; possibly I was mistaken.)

Therefore, here's my hypothesis for what's going on:

- In Safari, when the generated stylesheet link has never been used before, it's async, so `getComputedStyle` picks up the color from the inline style.  On later loads, the generated stylesheet is already in cache when `getComputedStyle` runs, so its rule takes over.
- In Firefox, stylesheet links are always treated as async, so getComputedStyle always picks up the inline rule.
- In other browsers, the stylesheet link is interpreted synchronously (possibly because the browser can tell that a `data` URI doesn't need network time?) so is handled before `getComputedStyle` runs.

This is a weird enough edge case that I'm not certain which behavior could be described as "according to spec".

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What about in chrome?\

Comment: Chrome is same as safari: clean cache makes it act like firefox.

Comment: Chrome is not acting like that in my case. Either way it is red.

Comment: Why is this race condition?

Comment: Race condition as in which happens first, the getComputedStyle or the computing of the generated stylesheet.   Re Chrome: I could swear I saw it behaving like Safari at some point, but I'm no longer able to reproduce that.

Comment: Correct.  (For what it's worth I've now also tested Edge; it behaves like Chrome, always red.)

Comment: Actually this is not a race condition, as async operation whenever they happen they will be executed at end when the stack is empty. Am i right?

Comment: Clearly not, given that each browser is handling this completely differently.  :) But you're right that I've used a somewhat loose definition of "race condition", I'll remove that text.

Comment: Why not, isn't that what suppose to happen

Comment: You seem quite determined that it should be, but the browser vendors seem to differ.  I don't know that fetch is required to be async for data URIs.

Comment: I mean async operation handler would be executed at end, not that if fetch is async or not

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  That does seem to match FF and clean-cache safari's behavior.

Comment: I meant suppose you have an async event, won't the javascript look at event queue only when stack is empty, then it will look into the queue and execute the pending event handler.

Comment: I think the issue here is that some browser vendors are seeing the data uri, decoding and updating the DOM straight away, in some respects this in normal situations really shouldn't be an issue as the onload event is likely still getting called.  It would seem very odd for any Javascript code to rely on an async operation been in any particular execution order so in most cases won't be an issue.  The code presented is a very strange edge case, most likely easily fixed by Chrome dev's by placing all data:uri's into a setImediate type call.  This seem similar to Promise.then library disparity's.

Comment: @Keith If that async call finishes first then also the stack will be first complete its execution and when it is empty then the async call handler will execute. Am I right?

Comment: @SurajJain `If that async call finishes first` I think this is were things get interesting,.  If *any* `href` call should always be deemed `async` in theory it should never finish first and always get called at the end, I suppose it's down to what the specification says.  Take the promise spec -> `Promise.resolve("first").then((r) => console.log(r)); console.log("second");`  Even though `first` can be resolved instantly, the result should be `second`, `first`.. But I remember some none complaint Promise libs would actually do `first`,`second`.

Answer (score -2):

Try HTML or HTML5 (this is Chrome):

```
<span type="color:green">shouldn't this be green</span>
```